# After Update, The data from another Table will be deleted

Tags: laravel, controller

I Have two different database table named **Customers** and **Change_info_request**

customers will request of changing their infomation and it will stored in **Change_info_request** and me the admin will be the one who will approve for changing information.
after the update the information inside the **Change_info_request** will transfer to the **Customers table** and the data inside the **Change_info_request** will be deleted .

And that's is my problem, i want to do it in the same controller like this

**UpdateRequest**

```
 public function UpdateRequest(ClientUpdate $request){
    $res = Customer::where('id', $request->id)
                    ->update([
                        'first_name'  => $request->new_first_name,
                        'last_name'   => $request->new_last_name,
                        'birthdate'   => $request->new_birthdate,
                        'gender'      => $request->new_gender,
                        'pending_update_info' => 2,

                    ]);
        

    if($res) {
        return response()->wrap($res);
    } else {
        return response()->wrap(["message" => "something went wrong!"]);
    }
}
```

How will i delete the info from **Change_info_request** inside this controller ?
Sorry for the wrong grammar and im only a student that studying laravel.

Comment: it depends on the structure of your application, did you implement repository structure ? Do you have a class that is made to handle anything regarding your request/update system ? or do you do it on the model itself ? or you fill your controller with everything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have id of that row in Change_info_request table right?**

i have done this before this was my way:

i store new information in my table called edit-user (just like your Change_info_request ) and when i show them in admin dashboard i have their id!

when admin click on approve button it will send the id of that row to some function!
in function i find the row in edit-user table with id that i have, and replace my new data in my users table (your Customers table) and when i finished replacing data i will delete data from edit-user with that id!

```
Change_info_request::find('customer_id', $id)->delete();
```

with id of that row in edit-user(your Change_info_request table) table you can do anything
and of course your in Change_info_request table you should have user_id field

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Before your if condition, you can add something like:

```
$del = Change_info_request::find('customer_id', $request->id)->delete();
```